# pasar variables entre los metodos de un controlador laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Quisiera pasar una variable desde el metodo index que devuelve una vista, al metodo store. Puedo pasar una variable desde una funcion llamada protected function, la que tuve que implementar obligatoriamente como intermediario para poder pasar la variable al metodo store del la siguiente manera:

```
protected function getData(){
    $varmy = 180;
    return $varmy;
} 

public function store(Request $request){    
    $var = $this->getData();
    dd($var);
}
```

pero lo que no puedo hacer es capturar la variable del metodo index hacia la funcion protectd funcion y que el metodo store la reciba. espero haberme explicado. gracias genios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes definir tu variable en el método index, por ejemplo:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $variable_a_pasar= "Valor de variable";

    return view("nombre_de_carpeta.index", compact('variable_a_pasar'));
}
```

Con el método compact envías la variable que quieres mostrar o simplemente pasar a tu vista index. Luego en tu formulario que llama al métoto post debes agregar un input de tipo hidden, el cuál no es obligatorio que justamente sea de tipo hidden pues también puedes enviar con un input de tipo text:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'nombre_de_carpeta.store', 'method'=>'POST') !!}
     <input type="hidden" value={{$variable_a_pasar}} name="variable_a_pasar">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Y luego en tu método store capturas esa variable:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $variable_a_pasar = $request->variable_a_pasar;
     dd($variable_a_pasar);
}
```

Comment: Gracias mariano, tu explicacion fue muy clara y precisa.